# Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied but the parameter is supplied

Tags: c#, ado.net, visual-studio-2017

I am receiving an error stating "Procedure or function 'WidgetInsert' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied." However, I am supplying the parameter. When I use a quickwatch to view the command, the parameters collection is populated and the @Name parameter has a value. What am I missing?

```
internal static void WidgetInsert(string cnnString, Widget item)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[WidgetInsert]", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", item.Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", item.Description);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the stored procedure that this is calling as well.

Comment: Can't remember but do you need to specify `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlCommand is disposable, so should be in a using block. And you may want to take a look at "[can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)" .

Comment: The default CommandType is Text.  It's possible that the SqlCommand is simply running `[dbo].[WidgetInsert]` with no parameters because that is the text of the command.  Try as Charles said.

Comment: @CharlesMay that was my problem. "command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure" was missing.